# Which state to open estate account of decedent

Tags: united-states, bank-account, estate

My father passed away in New York without a Will and i live in Texas, only son and heir. Should i open up estate account in New York or Texas?

Comment: Does it really matter for anything?

Comment: @littleadv Isn't that basically what the OP's asking... is there a reason one state would be "better" than the other, or is there no difference. In the UK I don't think a roughly-equivalent situation would make a difference, but things might be different in the US.

Comment: @TripeHound I'm trying to understand the concept. How opening a bank account in Texas differs from NY? What does it even mean? I'm sure the OP had something in mind when they asked, but I just don't know what that may be.

Comment: Depends on what they mean by "estate account". Sounds like it has to hold money for the estate before it is legally transferred to the heir, in which case I could *imagine* it has to be in the state where the deceased resided. This is more a question about legal advice than it is about finance, though.